# RSYNC from an External Hard drive

Tags: linux, rsync

I want to use RSYNC for the incremental copy of a folder which has a considerable size. The source (a directory) resides on an External hard disk (as we cannot have a network link between the source and destination) and the destination is a local system. Every week , the HDD is formated and that same directory is re-copied inside the External Hard Disk (it reflects the same data + any changes that has occurred since we last copied the directory into our system). I was wondering whether RSYNC can perform an incremental copy in this particular case.
Thanking You

Answer (score 3):

Sure. You can use something similar to:

`rsync -av --delete <src> <dst>`

to replicate `src` to `dst`.

The first copy will be slow (all data must be copied), but successive ones will be much faster (only modified/added files will be copied).

Using the `--delete` switch tell rsync to delete files which are not in `src` anymore; using it, you should be able to avoid the regular re-formatting of the external drive.

If you are interested in keeping hystorical/versioned backup, rather then directly using `rsync`, give a look at [`rsnapshot`](http://rsnapshot.org): it is based on rsync, but adds integrated backup deletion/rotation.

Comment: Let me tell you guys the exact scenario:
each week , we receive this external hard disk with has around 900 gb data; we have to 'backup' this data into our system each time we receive this external hard drive.Needless to say ,copying the whole 900gb+ data each week is very redundant so that is why I am considering RSYNC for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been noted `rsync` can be used to make your backups.  If you already have a backup, `rsync` can be used to apply the incremental changes.  It also has features to save changes so you have historical backups using the `--backup` and related flags.

There are a number of backup solutions built on top of the `rsync` protocol designed to keep historical backups that may be more space efficient. I've been using [BackupPC](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/setting-up-backuppc-on-ubuntu/) to backup both Linux and Windows systems.  You would need to run it manually in your case.

Comment: scenario: 
each week , we receive this external hard disk with has around 900 gb data; we have to 'backup' this data into our system each time we receive this external hard drive.Needless to say ,copying the whole 900gb+ data each week is very redundant so that is why I am considering RSYNC for this purpose. Now the concern for me is that when we send back that hard drive it has be formated ; after a week the same process occurs: they RECOPY the same directory to the hard drive(with the changes of course) , they send it to us and we again, have to copy it in order to reflect the changes.

Comment: as far as I have read, RSYNC works with inodes and blocks.. so wouldn`t that drive formatting disallow rsync to work ??